# An inequality for the mgf using Jensen’s inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, moment-generating-functions, jensen-inequality

Given non-negative random variables $X_1,X_2,...$ how to show that 
$$\mathbb{E}\exp(t\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}X_i)\leq \sum\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}\mathbb{E}\exp(tX_i).$$
I think we should start with 
$$\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}X_i\leq \sum\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}X_i$$
and the apply Jensen's inequality, but I need help with clarification of the details

Comment: Are the $X_i$ independent?

Comment: I think this should hold for any $X_i$s but would also appreciate a help for the case they are independent.

Comment: It is always true that $e^{\max x_k} \le \sum_k e^{x_k}$ since the $\max$ is attained for some $k$ and $\exp$ is positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $t<0$ then $t \max_k X_k(\omega) \le t X_i(\omega)$ for all $i$ and if
$t \ge 0$ then $ t \max X_k(\omega) \le tX_i(\omega)$ for some $i$.

Hence $e^{t \max_k X_k(\omega) } \le \sum_k e^{t X_k(\omega)}$ and hence taking expectations
we have the desired result.

Comment: So it seems that we do not need the Jensen’s inequality, right?

Comment: Correct. ${}{}{}$

Comment: The answer is fine, but its presentation could be improved : simply observe that $$e^{t\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}X_i} \leq \sum\limits_{1\leq i\leq n} e^{tX_i}.$$
 holds since the r.h.s is a  sum of non-negative terms, and the l.h.s is one of these terms, then take expectation. (This avoids the unncessary discussion on the sign of $t$).

Comment: well this is included in one of your above comments...